# How to investigate and test IIS connection pooling / port reusing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, port, connection-pooling

We are developing a middleware solution in the form of an Azure service, and we're experiencing a port exhaustion issue. As I'm not aware of any tools within Azure that could provide me with some more insights here, I want to do some testing on my local IISExpress.
Our middleware solution (.NET Core Web API) connects with Azure Cosmos DB services and a wide range of other REST APIs. We thought that our code is stable and solid. Making use of the IHttpClientFactory for the Cosmos DB requests, and using RestSharp for all other API requests. But, there must be a leak. Some sub process is creating too many instances of a HttpClient or similar, and that causes messages like

```
"An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full"
```

Now, I'm simulating requests via Postman and I'm running some netstat commands at the same time. But I'm not able get the insights I'm looking for. Netstat just keeps listing IP's and port numbers. I don't even see the IPs which are behind the hostnames I'm connecting with.
So I'm a bit lost here.

Is there a way to ask netstat to only show what ports are in use by IISExpress? Or is there an even better way to get some insights on port usage?

What I'm going now is running this command while executing web requests in a loop, and see if the count of TIME_WAIT lines is increasing. But is this a reliable check?

```
netstat -ano  | select-string TIME_WAIT | measure-object
```

Comment: Are you creating a new HttpClient everytime you need one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question sounds exactly like you are creating a new HttpClient every time you open a connection.  This is incorrect behaviour and leads to exactly what you are experiencing.

As [per the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0), you create an HttpClient once, and reuse it.  There are cases where you may use more than one HttpClient (e.g. one per API you are calling), and sometimes you may need to 'refresh the dns', but generally, you create one and keep using it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0

Comment: I'm using a IHttpClientFactory via DI, which in turn creates a HttpClient. This factory should take care of caching the HttpMessageHandler, which in turn should take care of reusing ports. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: But, testing this, and making sure that it does what it should do, is what I want to do now.

Comment: " using RestSharp for all other API requests." - is that using IHttpClientFactory too?

Comment: While reading their docs, at first I assumed that it did. But after reading through a discussion on the latest release I doubt that it already does support it. Again another reason why I want to be able to exactly measure the number of ports that are being used by my app process.